# How do I set a value based upon other values?

Tags: entities

I have a content type of product, and want to set the postage cost for the item which is dependent upon length,width,height, weight but also product kind - e.g. hazardous items needing special courier etc. I have a series of prices for the various weights and size limits, so I'm wondering how can I utilise these prices for the postage field automatically.

At the moment, the prices aren't inserted in Drupal, would these prices be better as a separate content-type or as fields inside a courier content-type? If the latter would they be as easy to reference?

This is not for a commerce site, merely somewhere to manage all my stock from all the various suppliers - a product information manager.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a small number of settings to store, you might consider using [system_settings_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_settings_form/7) to store them in Drupal's variables table. Take a look at the core modules that implement this function for more examples.

If the rates group logically, and/or need to be edited by users, you might make a postage_rates content type with fields on that for the information that changes in addition to any constants set by an admin using the first method. You can then add a [entityreference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field from you product to the postage_rate.

Comment: Is it possible for the postage value to be shown / calculated dynamically? I don't intend to add entity references to a considerable amount of products, and if weight limits change in the future, I wouldn't have to change xxx,xxx hard-coded references!

Comment: Certainly.  The point of my suggestion is to avoid creating a maintenance problem by placing the postage rates directly into your code.  You can calculate and set a field value in [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) using an [entity wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers).